# cocoon rails, how to get atached file name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im using cocoon to attach files. I need to be able to remove file when editing a question. Im stuck on getting the exact file name to remove when rendering edit

```
       div.edit_question
  =form_for @question, remote: true do |f|     
    = f.label :title, class: 'label_hidden' 
    = f.text_field :title
    br
    = f.label :body, class: 'label_hidden'
    = f.text_area :body 
    br 
    = f.fields_for :attachments do |f|                
      .nested-fields         
        = link_to_remove_association "remove #{ NAME HERE }", f     
    br
    = f.submit 'Update'
```

Answer (score 0):

Case is closed ))

```
=form_for @question, remote: true do |f|     
  = f.label :title, class: 'label_hidden' 
  = f.text_field :title
  br
  = f.label :body, class: 'label_hidden'
  = f.text_area :body 
  br
  - @question.attachments.each do |att| 
    = f.fields_for att do |f|                
      .nested-fields         
        = link_to_remove_association "remove #{ att.file.filename }", f     
  br
  = f.submit 'Update'
```

Comment: If this is the right answer, please mark it as correct answer :D